# Runtime.getRuntime().exec command fails with exit status 127 for all root activities

Tags: java, ssh, runtime, exec

I have a java code where it runs ssh command using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec`.
Below is the code:

```
package somepackage

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class Nodes {

    protected String ip = "1.2.3.4";
    private String privateKeyPath = "src/test/resources/devopskey";
    private String username = "devops";
    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Class.class.getName());

    public void executeCommand(String command) {
        try {
            log.info("Executing command " + command + " on " + this.ip);
            String ssh = "ssh -i " + privateKeyPath + " " + username + "@" + this.ip;
            String cmd = ssh + " \"" + command + "\"";
            log.info("Executing: " + cmd);
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                output.append(line).append("\n");
            }

            log.info(output.toString());
            int exitStatus = process.waitFor();
            log.info("Exit status: " + exitStatus);
            if (exitStatus != 0) {
                log.error("Failed to execute command: " + command + " on ip: " + this.ip);
            }
            else
                log.info("Command executed successfully");


        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Nodes().executeCommand("sudo ls /root");
    }
}
```

I get the below output:

```
23:20:08.512 [main] INFO java.lang.Class - Executing command ls /root on 1.2.3.4
23:20:08.538 [main] INFO java.lang.Class - Executing: ssh -i src/test/resources/devopskey devops@1.2.3.4 "sudo ls /root"
23:20:10.078 [main] INFO java.lang.Class - 
23:20:10.084 [main] INFO java.lang.Class - Exit status: 127
23:20:10.084 [main] ERROR java.lang.Class - Failed to execute command: ls /root on ip: 1.2.3.4
```

The same if I run on my local machine, below is the output:

```
joshi-mac$ ssh -i src/test/resources/devopskey devops@1.2.3.4 "sudo ls /root"
buildPlane.deb
node-v10.16.3-linux-x64
node-v10.16.3-linux-x64.tar.xz
```

In java code if I change the command params to just `ls` instead of `sudo ls /root` it works fine.
Also if I run with `ls /root` I get the same issue as exit-status *127*.
All root permission activities are not working. Please help.

Comment: Also I dont have access to root password or devops user password

Answer (score -1):

Please use ProcessBuilder class to execute any batch/sh file or OS command instead of Runtime class.

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(comandAndargList);
```